# SQL Server Group by clause - Simple stuff

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with questions and answers and sessionid.

Sometimes the same person (sessionid) will answer the same question more than 1 time, and that gets stored in the table.

The `qapp_answer` table content looks something like this:

```
Id, SessionID, QNumber, Qanswer
72     11         1       3
73     11         1       4
74     11         2       1
75     11         2       3
76     11         3       1
```

So, I only want each `Qnumber` to be displayed one time (so 3 rows in total), and basically just use their latest answer for display (`Qanswer`).

This is the code so far:

```
select Qnumber, Qanswer 
from qapp_answers
where sessionid = 11
group by QNumber, Qanswer
```

And it returns 5 rows.

Should be simple, but i havent used SQL for years.

Answer (score 4):

You can basically use `ROW_NUMBER()` which generates sequential number based on the group specified. The query belows group the records by `QNumber` and generates sequential number sorted by `ID` in descending order. The latest `ID` for every group has the value of `1` so you need to filter out records that has a generated value of `1`.

```
SELECT ID, SessionID, QNumber, Qanswer
FROM
    (
        SELECT  ID, SessionID, QNumber, Qanswer,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY QNumber ORDER BY ID Desc) rn
        FROM    tableName
        WHERE   SessionID = 11
    ) a
WHERE   a.rn = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dc3c8/2)